# Disable Button when clicked in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I made two button component and when i click one i would like to render the other onClick to be able to disable (since they don't look the same).

```
    const match = id;
    const checkId = this.state.pokemon.includes(match);

            {!checkId || this.state.isDisabled === true ? (
                        <button
                            onClick={() =>
                                this.setState({
                                    isDisabled: true
                                })
                            }
                        >
                            Get Pokemon
                        </button>
                    ) : (
                        <Button disabled/>
                    )}
                </div>
```

The problem is that the button disable is only rendering when i refresh because is meeting the conditions of check Id but i have trouble Switching to the disable button directly after the click

Comment: Is it `button` or `Button`? Also, yes, you should move a single button where the condition determines its `disabled` value. Edit: sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/naughty-kowalevski-1iqis

Comment: Thank you, It's working but disabling all the button (i'm mapping) any way to deactivate only one ??

Comment: Sure, but you need a separate `state` variable for each button obviously, i.e. an array.

Answer (score 1):

Replace to

```
     <button disabled={!checkId || this.state.isDisabled}
                        onClick={() =>
                            this.setState({
                                isDisabled: true
                            })
                        }
                    />
                        Get Pokemon
       </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

The following condition seems faulty:

`{!checkId || this.state.isDisabled === true ? (`

In my opinion the condition should be changed to:

`!checkId || !this.state.isDisabled`, because from what I see, whenever the button is clicked the `isDisabled` state is set to `true` which evaluates the condition to truthy, hence, the falsy case is never executed.

If you need to execute it once, per `match`, you can even change the condition to be:

`(!checkId && !this.state.isDisabled)`

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you for the answer but i still get the same, it execute only when i refresh the page and not directly when i click on the button

Comment: can you show the full code??